# alternative for "but not" in formal language

Tags: word-choice, formal-language

I am looking for an alternative for the expression "but not" in the sentence:

"the parameters satisfies the condition A, **but not** the condition B."

It is a sentence that will be used in a scientific paper, so I need a more formal way to rewrite the sentence above.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Why do you think the sentence provided is not formal?

Comment: We wouldn't usually say "**the** condition X" - *condition X* is like a name, so it doesn't require a determiner.

Comment: **the parameters satisfy**  NOT  "the parameters satisfies"

Comment: Good point @Glorfindel. I always thought that the "but" word should be avoid in the formal writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"formal" language means using simple terms for simple things and only using "fancy" or rare words for their specific meaning.

"...but not..." is entirely formal.